# Android iText signature unhandled Exception

Tags: java, android, itext

Im working on a  digital signature solution

im looking for signature panels within a pdf document using a solution i found here

[Itext get field coordinates from existing pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066141/itext-get-field-coordinates-from-existing-pdf)

i then apply a signature to the location of the signature field, and it should look like the user has signed the document

however when the following line executes it exits the sub

```
for(String signame : fields.getBlankSignatureNames())
```

its a bit of a mystery as there are two signature fields within the fields object

any help  would be appreciated

heres my full code

```
import android.os.Environment;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class PDFStamper {

    public static void main()  {



        try {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sample.pdf");

            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sample-signed.pdf"));

            Image image = Image.getInstance(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/signature.png");

            float scaler = 10;

            image.scalePercent(scaler);



        String pdfFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sample.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);

        AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();


        for(String signame : fields.getBlankSignatureNames()) {
            List<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions = fields.getFieldPositions(signame);
            Rectangle rect = positions.get(0).position; // In points:
            float left = rect.getLeft();
            float bTop = rect.getTop();
            float width = rect.getWidth();
            float height = rect.getHeight();

            int page = positions.get(0).page;
            Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(page);
            float pageHeight = pageSize.getTop();
            float top = pageHeight - bTop;

            System.out.print(signame + "::" + page + "::" + left + "::" + top + "::" + width + "::" + height + "\n");

            //put content over
            PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(page);

            content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(page);

            image.setAbsolutePosition(left, bTop);
            content.addImage(image);

        }

                pdfStamper.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        }
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: When encountering problems with iText on Android, it is always good to check whether you're using the Android port [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) or the Java version. The Java version of iText is not suited for use on Android because it has some dependencies on `java.awt`, `javax.nio`, etc... This can result in strange exceptions. With every new elease of iText, we also provide a release of iTextG which is tailored for use on Android and Google App Engine.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for your input. I do believe I have used the iTextG release. Is there any way I can confirm this? I'm wondering if it's the java import I make in the class?

Comment: @mkl I will upload this later today after work